# Is there a way to set Windows 7 Backups to backup every time a user logs off instead of based on time?

Tags: windows-7

Question pretty much says it all. I'd like to be able to set Windows 7 Backup to backup my files to the network each time I log off rather than at a set time each day.

Is this possible? If not, can you recommend a good alternative?

Comment: What are you trying to back up?  Is the system on a domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, depending on how you want to do it, a simple XCOPY, or using Windows Backup, or file synchronization.

You could create a batch file using either XCOPY or Windows backup (lookup the command line, you can find it), and then do gpedit.msc>User Configuration>Scripts>Logoff and put the batch file as a logoff script (assumes not using home versions, but Pro).

The other thing that is easier and comes to mind. If you have a user location on the file server, and all your documents are in "My Documents", you can simply go to Start>Documents and right click. Set your network location as the new location. It will ask it you want to move your current documents. Turn on off-line files and set your Documents to synchronize. Then when you log off, it will synchroniz them automatically so you have a local copy and network one, which is the real location.

Comment: If I were to use XCOPY, I would use all these switches -m (only copy those files that have changed, and resets the archive bit), -s (gets subdirectories), -c (continues even on error), -i (If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.), -q (quiet), -h (hidden files), -o (copies ACL info), -y (surpress prompting).

Comment: I like the file syncing and offline file use option...going to look in to setting that up as it appears to be the most seemless option for my end users. Will give the check once setup. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware offline files has a size limit in some cases and that not all files can be made available offline without making changes to the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is on a domain you can redirect the desired folder to the server and then enable Volume Shadow Copy on the folder(s) as an added protection against deletion of key files. Then the server backup process would capture files on the regular schedule.  More info might help with more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set up a back up script [like so](http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/create-a-windows-daily-backup-script).

This is basically a batch file with a command like the following:

"xcopy c:\test* x:\backup\%date:~0,3%* /Y /Q /S"

XCopy is for large files, some of the other options are for stopping prompt.
Make sure to test your .bat file.

Please test it with you specific configuration.

2) Open the local group policy editor [like so](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3652-local-group-policy-editor-open.html).

3) Follow this explanation for activiting your script at [log off](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753404.aspx).

4) Log off and it should work.

I have done this before but please check it for your configuration etc.

Best of luck...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Google turned up:

http://www.simple-tech.info/run-windows-backup-sdclt-in-command-line-to-backup-system-at-logoff-or-computer-shutdown.aspx